# Ubuntu Budgie doesn't show colored Emojis

Tags: themes, emoji, ubuntu-budgie

So while I was using Ubuntu Budgie in a more productive way, I installed spotify to listen to my playlists- then I realized that I can not see the emojis which are included in my playlist names ...

I tried to switch the "Appearance" in "Themes & Layouts", because I thought that this would be a theme-based problem/property.

I searched a while in the internet and got the solution:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this package in the search results:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/bionic/fonts-noto-color-emoji

So it could be, that this (in my opinion) important package is missing with Ubuntu Budgie ...
However- installing it is easy and now Emojis are displayed in a better, colored way :)

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]